# Making a custom field "read-only" when displayed via javascript custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Okay, I know this is a very specific question, but maybe someone out there can help:

**BACKGROUND:**
I have modified the original custom code for a "Mass Edit" button so that:

> {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
>   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}
>
> var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.SelfSufficiency_Evaluation__c)};  
>   var strIDs=''; 
>   if (records[0] == null) 
>   { 
>   alert('Please select all of the Domain records for the Client in order to input scores'); 
>   } 
>   else 
>   { 
>   for (var n=0; n
>   { 
>   if(strIDs == '') 
>   strIDs = records[n]; 
>   else 
>   strIDs = strIDs + "," + records[n] ; 
>   } 
>   window.location.href = '/apex/MassManager__MassEdit?selectedRecords='+strIDs + '&selectedObject=SelfSufficiency_Evaluation__c&selectedFields=Domain_Type__c,Intake_Score__c,X30_Days_Post_Birth_Score__c,X90_Days_Post_Birth_Score__c,Exit_Score__c,Aftercare_Intake_Score__c,X6_months_Aftercare_Score__c,X12_months_Aftercare_Score__c,X18_months_Aftercare_Score__c,X24_months_Aftercare_Score__c&retURL='+ window.location.href; 
>   }

Basically this custom button allows us to mass edit the custom fields listed towards the end on the code.

**QUESTION:** 
Is it possible to make the first custom field "Domain_Type__c" read-only via javascript? Already tried via page layout but didn't work, hence my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making a formula field that is essentially the value of `Domain_Type__c` then using that field in your URL instead of the `Domain_Type__c`? I do not use that package so not sure if you can trick it like this or not.

Comment: @Eric Unfortunately, even though the formula field is "read-only", it still shows up as "editible" in the rendered mass edit screen.

Comment: Hmmm.  They must be doing custom inputs or something as a formula field is never editable